# Limit of an expression with Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

[image]

> $$\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{-\cos x}\cdot\frac{\sin^2x}{e^x-e^{-x}}=
> \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{-\cos x}\cdot\frac{x^2+2R_1x+R_1^2}{2x+\bar R_1(x)}=
> \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{-\cos x}\cdot\frac{x+2R_1+\frac{R_1^2}x}{2+\frac{\bar R_1(x)}x}
> \overset{x\to0^+}\longrightarrow0$$

I don't understand how they get to $0$.

On the last expression, the left side equal to $-2$ while the right side is $R_1$, how the multiplication became $0$?

Thanks

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). I have tried to edit text based on the picture you've included - please, edit it further to get it to the form you're satisfied with.

Comment: What's $R_1$ and $R_2$ ?? @Alon

Comment: $R_1$ itself tends to zero with $x\to 0$, so the multiplication of $0$ in $-2$ is $0$.

Comment: Would maybe rewriting it like this help to clarify the result: $\frac{x+2R_1+\frac{R_1^2}x}{2+\frac{\bar R_1(x)}x}= x\cdot \frac{1+\frac{2R_1}x+\frac{R_1^2}{x^2}}{2+\frac{\bar R_1(x)}x}$.

Answer (score 3):

$$A=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{-\cos (x)}\cdot\frac{\sin^2(x)}{e^x-e^{-x}}= -\coth (x)\sin (x) \tan (x) $$

Rewrite it as
$$A=-x \color{orange}\cdot{\frac x{\tanh(x)}}\cdot\color{green} {\frac {\sin(x)} x}\cdot \color{red} {\frac {\tan(x)} x}$$ Each of the colored term tends to $1$; so, close to $x=0$, $A\sim -x \to 0$.

If you want Taylor series
$$A=-\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^3}{45}+O\left(x^5\right) \right)\cdot\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right) \right)\cdot\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right) \right)$$
$$A=-x-\frac{x^3}{2}+O\left(x^5\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{-\cos x}\cdot\frac{\sin^2x}{e^x-e^{-x}} \sim \frac{x^2}{e^{-x}(e^{2x}-1)} \sim \frac{x}{2}$$ when $x \rightarrow 0$